# Visibility on an alien world

Tags: optics, visible-light, astrophysics, atmospheric-science, estimation

I asked this over on Worldbuilding, and I was told it'd be best to try here instead:

First, I should probably mention that I'm really bad at mathematics.

I'm working on a scientifically plausible alien world, and one of the toughest things thus far has been basically anything involving the atmosphere.

- The **star** is 47 UMa (radius 1.21 * sun, temperature 5872K, luminosity 6.087E+26 W).
- The **planet** is 47 UMa b, with a fictional moon (47 UMa b-i) being the focus.
- The **moon** has an insolation flux of 491.0346231 W m⁻ 2 (35.764% of Earth's). Its *gravity* is 1.209g (mass 1.557* Earth, radius 1.135* Earth), and its surface temperature is an average of ~70c (I *know* this will be difficult to explain; just know this isn't meant for human habitation).
- The **atmosphere** has an average density of ~4.432 kg/m³, and a sea-level pressure of 4
  atm. Its composition is 65.95% Nitrogen, 25% Argon, 9% Oxygen, and
  0.05% CO2, though that may change as I've been looking into the possibility of Hydrogen as a greenhouse gas.

What I want to know is how poor visibility would be (in simplified circumstances) with all this in mind. The amount of rayleigh scattering versus Earth would be great too, if possible.

For context, anything involving the moon is a combination of my own calculators and those from the "Worldsmith" spreadsheet by Artifexian. The parameters for the star and planet are from [NASA's exoplanet catalogue.](https://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu/)

Comment: Welcome to the club. We basically got the initial estimates for the Martian and Venusian atmospheres wrong by orders of magnitude, I believe. So what's the likelihood that anybody can tell you what visibility looks like on an alien world that nobody has even seen in a telescope? Would you like next week's weather report with that? It will be sunny with occasional cloud cover and ground fog that won't lift until 3pm.

Comment: This sort of question doesn't really work here.  Firstly it's a given at this point that anything short of a major analysis of a planet (knowings it's detailed topography and surface features) would produce anything more than a ballpark guess of what you want to know.  Secondly filling the site up with fictional calculations (even if they were practical) would not be useful to the site, which is here to explain *concepts*, not solve specific problems.  Worldbuilding is actually the correct place for this question.

Comment: *needlessly detailed* Insolation flux to ten significant digits!

Comment: If I've done my math right your moon has an escape velocity only about 10–15% higher than Earth's.  All other things being equal, I'd expect hydrogen to escape from your planet as easily as it does from Earth's atmosphere.  If you're going for realism I think you're probably better off using good old CO2 as your greenhouse gas to get the surface temperatures you want.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert

This is the study where I got the idea of an H2 greenhouse from. It's based on the idea of volcanic outgassing outpacing atmospheric loss.

https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1702/1702.08618.pdf

Answer (score 3):

The sea level pressure is about 4 times greater than Earth's. The temperature is a factor of 343/290 or so higher, so the number density of gas molecules at sea level is just over 3 times higher.

The density of scatterers is primarily what determines the optical depth to Rayleigh scattering. The atmospheric gas composition is not different enough to Earth's to make much difference. So that would appear to be your answer.

Having said that, if your atmosphere contains no dust, particulates or other aerosols then that will improve the transparency, since these are important sources of scattering at green and red wavelengths in the Earth's atmosphere.

Answer (score 1):

I am only interested in

> Finally, and **optionally** (as with Rayleigh scattering), if anyone could explain the Beer-Lambert equation to someone whose maths knowledge only goes as far as logarithms, I'd greatly appreciate it!

For a thin slice $\mathrm dx$ long of a material being subjected to light of intensity $I$, the rate of intensity decrease per length is a tiny constant $\mu$ multiplied by the incoming intensity. The above statement is written in equation form as
$$\frac{\mathrm dI}{\mathrm dx}=-I\mu\tag{1}$$
You can see it as, as the intensity passes through the material by length $\mathrm dx$, an amount of intensity equal to $I\mu$ is subtracted from the incoming intensity to give the outgoing intensity.

You said that you are aware of logarithms. Dividing both sides by $I$, we will get
$$\int\frac1I\frac{\mathrm dI}{\mathrm dx}\mathrm dx=-\mu\int_0^x\mathrm dx^\prime$$
$$\int_{I_0}^I\frac{\mathrm dI^\prime}{I^\prime}=-\mu x$$
$$\ln\left(\frac{I}{I_0}\right)=-\mu x$$
$$\frac{I}{I_0}=e^{-\mu x}$$
$$I=I_0 e^{-\mu x}$$
where we have used the known property of the natural logarithm, that
$$\int\frac1x\mathrm dx=\ln x-\ln x_0$$
for some constant $x_0$, and that exponentials are the function inverses of logarithms.

The Beer-Lambert Law is thus obtained. It can be seen as the effect of what happens when stuff passes through a material and there are low probabilities of being scattered off. We have also assumed that the probabilities of interaction is so low that being scattered twice is not likely.